# How to store html into a javascript variable without parsing it, to be just like it is

Tags: javascript, html

Currently im doing like this but internet explorer 7 doesn't recognize it:

```
    gf.klass["LoginSkin"] = ""+<r><![CDATA[<div>
        <ul>
            <li value="login" >
                login
            </li>
            <li value="cancel">
                cancel
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>]]></r>;;
```

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense. Mozilla based browsers support something like this with E4X ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/E4X ), but if you want something general you'll need to go in more detail and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you've quoted is invalid JavaScript. The valid equivalent would be:

```
gf.klass["LoginSkin"] = '<div>\
    <ul>\
        <li value="login" >\
            login\
        </li>\
        <li value="cancel">\
            cancel\
        </li>\
    </ul>\
</div>';
```

Note the use of the trailing backslash to continue the literal to the next line. This is per Section 7.8.4 ("String Literals") of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Note that the leading characters of subsequent lines *are* part of the string (just as they are in your CDATA section).

Answer (score 0):

you have element.innerHTML method to retrieve HTML of subelements !